# java play framework 2.1.3 How retrive a routes object

Tags: playframework-2.0

i would like to know how is possible retrive a route object from a string in the global.java class because im trying to make a dynamic module routing: i don't want to edit my 
main routes each time i add a module (sub-project) as

-> /mymodule  mymodule.Routes

So to avoid this,i'm tring to load the target routes depending of the URI path.
/module/mymodule

I tryed to write some code as follow inside onRouteRequest()

```
Class.forName("mymodule.Routes").routes.lift(request);
```

but it fail, any suggestions?

**edit 1**: in play 1 was possible something like that:

```
/{controller}/{action} {controller}.{action}
```

But in play2 seems dont work as well

**edit 2**: my current Global.java is

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Play;
import play.api.mvc.Handler;
import play.mvc.Http;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings
{

@Override
public Handler onRouteRequest(Http.RequestHeader request)
{
    String path = request.path();
    if (path.startsWith("/module/"))
    {
        String[] paths = path.split("/");
        String router = paths[2];
        try
        {
            return (Handler) Class.forName(router + ".Routes", true, Play.application().classloader()).newInstance();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return super.onRouteRequest(request);
}
}
```

And he found the correct routes but Instantation Exception is thrown

Comment: Calling `newInstance()` seems to fail here. Does your router has parameterless public constructor?

Comment: The problem is what @kapep mentioned. The `Routes` class doesn't have a default constructor. It has a bunch of static methods. There is one called `handlerFor` that seemed promising but it takes a `play.api.mvc.RequestHeader` object, not the Java-version `play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader` that is passed to the `onRouteRequest` method.

Comment: infact i reflected Routes in static way but i found these problems. So alternative solutions?

Comment: Can you create a test project so we don't have to replicate all your work but try to figure out what is going wrong with your setup. Upload it to github or wherever and share the link here. It's much higher probability that we can help this way.

Comment: https://github.com/jstar88/PlayTests here there is the code, but you cannot reflect around the framework with java because the framework is built with scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit demoralizing the java inferiority against scala in this framework. After some days i decided to perform the automatic handling writing new contents in the main routes file each time server is started.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings
{
@Override
public void onStart(Application app)
{
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    File route = app.getFile("/conf/routes");
    File[] modules = app.getFile("/modules").listFiles();

    String newContents = "# start of autogenerated code" + newline;
    for (File module : modules)
    {
        String moduleLow = module.getName().toLowerCase();
        newContents += "-> /module    " + moduleLow + ".Routes " + newline;
    }
    newContents += "# end of autogenerated code" + newline;
    editRoute(route, newContents, newline);

}

private void editRoute(File route, String newContents, String newline)
{
    try
    {
        FileReader f = new FileReader(route);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        String contents = "";
        while (true)
        {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            contents += s + newline;
        }
        br.close();

        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(route);
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(w);
        b.write(newContents + contents);
        b.flush();
        b.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop(Application app)
{
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    File route = app.getFile("/conf/routes");
    try
    {
        FileReader f = new FileReader(route);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        String contents = "";
        boolean startAutoCode = false;
        boolean endAutoCode = false;
        while (true)
        {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            if (s.contains("# start of autogenerated code"))
            {
                startAutoCode = true;
            }
            else if (s.contains("# end of autogenerated code"))
            {
                endAutoCode = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (!startAutoCode || endAutoCode)
            {
                contents += s + newline;
            }
        }
        br.close();

        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(route);
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(w);
        b.write(contents);
        b.flush();
        b.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```